# Prove that $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (-1)^k$ $\sum_{j=2^{k-1}}^{2^{k}-1} \frac{1}{j\ln j}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am stuck with showing convergence of the following infinite series problem:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (-1)^k \sum_{j=2^{k-1}}^{2^{k}-1} \frac{1}{j\ln j}$$

I think I can prove it using Alternating Series Test, but it is hard to show that series is monotone... How can I solve this problem with some basic infinite series tests?

Can you help me?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Put $a_k=\sum_{j=2^{k-1}}^{2^{k}-1} \frac{1}{j\ln j}$. Then $$a_{k+1}=\sum_{j=2^{k-1}}^{2^{k}-1} \frac{1}{2j\ln(2 j)}+\sum_{j=2^{k-1}}^{2^{k}-1} \frac{1}{(2j+1)\ln(2 j+1)}$$ Use now that $ (2j+1)\log(2j+1)\geq 2j\log (2j)$ to show that $a_{k+1}\leq a_k$.

Comment: Wow. That's a great solution. Thank you so much!